# Undefined index from AJAX POST to PHP?

Tags: php, json, ajax

I'm new to this community and a beginner with programming. I'm trying to post a JSON data with AJAX to another PHP file and my code is as follow:

--- AJAX code ---

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

//other codes in between

      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
          //alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
          alert(data.orderID);

          // Call your server to save the transaction
          return fetch('/paypal-transaction-complete', {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify({                    
              orderID: data.orderID
            })
          });

        });

        var orderid_data = data.orderID;

        $.ajax({
            url: "test_parse.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {'order_ID': orderid_data },
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
        });
```

--- PHP code ---

```
var_export($_POST);
echo $_POST["order_ID"];
```

I've realised that my $_POST return an empty array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Change `data: {'order_ID': orderid_data },` to `data: {order_ID: orderid_data },` Or simply look at the output from a `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Since you said you are new to programming, please dont be offended by this question: Are you opening `test_parse.php` in your browser directly?

Comment: Did you try the code change I suggested?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah, i've tried them. but it doesnt work :( I've been on this for hours already...

print_r($_POST) shows Array(). I think theres an issue with the AJAX side, but i have no idea where it is?

Comment: @Pilan No worries, I'm running both files on my localhost with wamp

Comment: Yes, but did you type `[...]test_parse.php` in your adressbar?

Comment: @Pilan yep! so like localhost/[...]/test_parse.php

btw, both the ajax and php files are on the same file directory.

Comment: Okay, as I suspected. I'll post it as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you open `[...]test_parse.php` directly in your browser, there is no POST-data present anymore, therefor its empty.

The POST-Data is part of the request. If you open it manually in the browser you perform a GET request.

**What can you do to see the `var_export`?**

You can use Chrome or Firefox for example both have Developer-Tools which allow you to trace the exact POST-Request you performed via ajax.

For Chome:

- Hit `F12` to open the Dev Tools
- Navigate to `Network`

Now perform your Ajax-Post-Request and find it in the Network list. By clicking on the requests you will see all details you will need. Most Imporant for you is `Response`

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for writing out the answer!! so am I supposed to use an AJAX GET instead of POST?

Comment: You are welcome. No no, you are supposed to use the Developer-Tools :)

Comment: Is there any way I can parse it into a PHP file? Because I would need the "orderID" for another PHP file later on. :)

Comment: There are many ways to memorize a value. The right one depends on the use-case. You can do it via SESSION oder Database or File etc.

Comment: using the session_start() seems like an easier method, but how can I store a JSON string/object into the $_SESSION variable with php?

Comment: <?php $_SESSION[order_id] = ?> JSON.stringify(data.orderID) <?php ; ?>

does this method somewhat make sense? hahha D:

Comment: `$_SESSION['some_key'] = json_encode($someVar);` use `$someVar = json_decode($_SESSION['some_key']);` to get it back as var. But you need to save the order_id so there is no saving as json neccesary

Comment: Pilan, I'm so sorry to be bothering you! But...

do I place this "$_SESSION['some_key'] = json_encode($someVar);" into the AJAX file? or the test_parse.php? Because from what I understand, json_encode() is a PHP function, and I can't have a JSON obj as my parameter.

        var orderid_data = data.id;
        $_SESSION['order_id'] = json_encode(orderid_data);

Comment: Better you tell me what you actually trying to do :)

Comment: Really appreciate your help so far! :) I'm using the paypal API to create an order. (1) So on the client side (w/ the AJAX code), the client clicks on a button (by paypal) whicn directs him to a link to log in to the paypal account and confirm the payment. (2) after payment is done, as seen on the code in my question, an alert to show the OrderID (in json) will be generated. (3) Afterwhich I would need the OrderID to input it into another API to retrieve the order's details. So over here, I'm trying to store the orderID into a session variable/post it to another PHP file. :)

Comment: Well, there is a comment in the code `Call your server to save the transaction` this IS the part where you place your `test_parse.php`. Everything you do has to be in the function after `.then`. Thats pretty tough stuff for a beginner. If you want to know why it has to be in the function, have a look at callbacks and promises.

Comment: "$_SESSION['some_key'] = json_encode($someVar);" -> do I place this after the .then within the function on the JS script?

Comment: This question tells me you should learn the basics first. Try to walk before you try to fly :) - The quoted code is PHP - you ask me if you should insert PHP code in your JS...

Comment: This is a school's assignment so it's kinda urgent. But yeah I understand that it's impossible to insert PHP into JS - so I'm not sure how I can store a JSON string into a session variable? The only way I can think of is to use AJAX, which I'm stuck now because it doesn't work...?